# Cannot access container started in a node process until the process is exited

Tags: node.js, docker

I created a container using docker-cli-js in a node process, but got `ECONNREFUSED connect` error message when trying to access it from within the same process.

However, after exiting the process, I was able to access the container. Is this expected a behaviour. Is there away I can access the container from the same node process that started it?

Answer (score 0):

It appears I simply tried to access it too quickly. Now resolved but waiting a bit before trying to access the container